# Pyspark: Concatenating values into lists within certain time range

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe that contains `id`, `timestamp` and `value` column. I am trying to create a dataframe that first groups rows with the same id, then separate the ones that are, say longer than 2 weeks apart and finally concatenate their `value` into a list.

I have already tried to use `rangeBetween()` Window function. It doesn't quite deliver what I want. I think the code below illutrates my question better:

My dataframe `sdf`:

```
+---+-------------------------+-----+
|id |tts                      |value|
+---+-------------------------+-----+
|0  |2019-01-01T00:00:00+00:00|a    |
|0  |2019-01-02T00:00:00+00:00|b    |
|0  |2019-01-20T00:00:00+00:00|c    |
|0  |2019-01-25T00:00:00+00:00|d    |
|1  |2019-01-02T00:00:00+00:00|a    |
|1  |2019-01-29T00:00:00+00:00|b    |
|2  |2019-01-01T00:00:00+00:00|a    |
|2  |2019-01-30T00:00:00+00:00|b    |
|2  |2019-02-02T00:00:00+00:00|c    |
+---+-------------------------+-----+
```

My approach:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

DAY_SECS = 3600 * 24
w_spec = Window \
         .partitionBy('id') \
         .orderBy(F.col('tts').cast('timestamp').cast('long')) \
         .rangeBetween((Window.currentRow)-(14*DAY_SECS), Window.currentRow)
out = sdf \
        .withColumn('val_seq', F.collect_list('value').over(w_spec))
```

Output:

```
+---+-------------------------+-----+-------+
|id |tts                      |value|val_seq|
+---+-------------------------+-----+-------+
|0  |2019-01-01T00:00:00+00:00|a    |[a]    |
|0  |2019-01-02T00:00:00+00:00|b    |[a, b] |
|0  |2019-01-20T00:00:00+00:00|c    |[c]    |
|0  |2019-01-25T00:00:00+00:00|d    |[c, d] |
|1  |2019-01-02T00:00:00+00:00|a    |[a]    |
|1  |2019-01-29T00:00:00+00:00|b    |[b]    |
|2  |2019-01-01T00:00:00+00:00|a    |[a]    |
|2  |2019-01-30T00:00:00+00:00|b    |[b]    |
|2  |2019-02-02T00:00:00+00:00|c    |[b, c] |
+---+-------------------------+-----+-------+
```

My desired output:

```
+---+-------------------------+---------+
|id |tts                      |val_seq|
+---+-------------------------+---------+
|0  |2019-01-02T00:00:00+00:00|[a, b]   |
|0  |2019-01-25T00:00:00+00:00|[c, d]   |
|1  |2019-01-02T00:00:00+00:00|[a]      |
|1  |2019-01-29T00:00:00+00:00|[b]      |
|2  |2019-01-30T00:00:00+00:00|[a]      |
|2  |2019-02-02T00:00:00+00:00|[b, c]   |
+---+-------------------------+---------+
```

To sum it up: I want to group rows in `sdf` with the same `id`, and further concatenate the `value` for rows that are not longer than 2 weeks apart and finally only show these rows.

I am really new to pyspark so any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code should work:

```
 w_spec = Window \
                 .partitionBy('id') \
                 .orderBy(F.col('tts').cast('timestamp').cast('long')) \
                 .rangeBetween((Window.currentRow)-(14*DAY_SECS), Window.currentRow)
       
        out1 = df.withColumn('val_seq', F.collect_list('value').over(w_spec)).withColumn('occurrences_in_5_min',F.count('tts').over(w_spec))
```

w_spec2 = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(col("occurrences_in_5_min").desc())

Out2=out1.withColumn("rank",rank().over(w_spec2)).filter("rank==1")